# Unresolved reference: fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

i have encountered some errors in my kotlin code.
The code is as below:

```
'''package com.mohamed.focuscounter

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment                        //(line4)
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup'''

'''class AvailableFragment : Fragment() {                       //(line 9)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_available, container, false)
    }
}'''

 The Errors encountered is as follows:
   1.unresolved reference:fragment (line 4)
   2.unresolved reference:Fragment (line 9)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Make sure that you have added the `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"` dependency in your app-level `build.gradle`

Comment: Yes i have added but still get the same errors

Comment: just believe in yourself!

Comment: @NinjaAdoberGab What?? Lol!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Fragment's dependency in your app `build.gradle` file

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5"
```